# jBPM 7.0 create custom start timer

Tags: jbpm

does anybody know a tutorial, which describes how to develop a custom start timer for jBPM 7.0 similar to [this](http://fxapps.blogspot.de/2015/04/creating-custom-work-item-handler-in.html) tutorial for custom work items?

Comment: I guess its not possible to create custom timer start event. I am not sure about your requirement, but you can write your time calculation logic in java class and for jBPM process use signal start event, and based on time calculation send signal which will trigger the process execution.

Comment: The process I would like to create depents on multiple factors: 

   - time of day
   - weekday
   - official holiday calendar
   - ...

All these factors determine the start time point of my process.

@Abhijit Humbe
Can you give me an example for your proposal, please?

Comment: refer to maven project https://github.com/abhijithumbe/jbpm6Examples/tree/master/jbpm6_SchedularService_StartProcessAtSpecificTime

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. The function of your example is what I'm looking for. But is it possible to create a module with this function? I need a module with this function, because some people, who need that, can't write in java or other programming languages. They need a module with drag and drop and properties to create a business process. It must be simple. Most of the business processes are created with the KIE Workbench web gui. Ideally the user gets a module/task/event with the clock/timer symbol like the others "Start Event" timer or the "Catching Intermediate Event" timer.